# what are the possible 3 outputs of this code C? fork()

Tags: c, fork

I am new to this fork statement, I have no idea fork method which is on c programs. could you tell me what are the three possible outputs for this code..

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("10\n");
    if (fork())
        printf("2\n");
    else
        printf("3\n");
    printf("4\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I only know one output of this it is

```
10
3
4
```

what are the other 2 output when `if (fork())` is true?

Comment: `fork()` creates a child process, by duplicating its parent. You should read about the `fork()` call online before posting here. http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork

Comment: Also, try running your code before posting. The output will never be `10 3 4`.

Answer (score 3):

The key to understanding it is simple: `fork()`, if successful, returns twice: in the parent, and in the child. In the parent, it returns the PID of the newborn child; in the child it returns 0;

`10 3 4` will never happen: if `3` is printed, it means a child process was created successfully (because `fork()` returned 0 on the child), so there are two processes that will print `4`. It is impossible to have only one 4 in the output, assuming that `fork()` was successful.

Here is the set of possible outputs:

- `10 2 4 3 4`: this happens if the parent executes everything first followed by the child. The parent prints `10 2 4` and then the child prints `3 4`.
- `10 2 3 4 4`: happens when the parent executes first, printing `2`, then the child executes and prints `3`, and then either the parent or the child prints `4`, and then the other prints `4`
- `10 3 4 2 4`: happens when the child executes first, printing `3` and `4`, then the parent resumes and prints `2` and `4`.
- `10 3 2 4 4`: happens when the child executes first, printing `3`, then the parent resumes and prints `2`, and then either the parent or the child prints `4`, and then the other prints the final `4`.
- `10 2 4`: happens when `fork()` fails and returns `-1`, in which case no child is created and thus you get the output of the original process only

If you run the program in a line-buffered terminal, these are all the possibilities. However, if you redirect output to a file, you may have a surprise and see `10` in the output more than once.

This happens because redirection to a file typically switches the buffering mode from line-buffered to fully buffered. Assuming the buffer size is greater than the 3 characters of the string `10\n` and that the buffer wasn't flushed in the meantime - also a reasonable assumption - the child will start with an output buffer that contains `10\n`. So, you end up having two `10\n` in the output.

Thus, the set of possible outputs can be extended in this case to include another `10` in every possibility before the child prints `3`:

- `10 2 4 10 3 4`
- `10 2 10 3 4 4`
- `10 10 3 4 2 4`
- `10 10 3 2 4 4`

Answer (score 2):

The program should output one of the following:

```
10 2 3 4 4
10 2 4 3 4
10 3 4 2 4
10 3 2 4 4
```

Since `fork()` returns twice, once for the parent and once for the child, 10 is printed once by the parent, the parent prints 2 and 4, and the client prints 3 and 4.

Since both parent and child are printing to the same console, and there's no definitive ordering of statements between the two processes, there are actually six possible outputs, four of which are distinct.